# Which account i need to use inside the "Configuration Wizards" for a new SharePoint 2013 on-premise

Tags: 2013, administration, installation, configuration, configuration-wizard

we have installed a new sharepoint enterprise server 2013. and now i want to run the "Configuration Wizards" from "Central Administration >> Configuration wizards":-

[image]

now on the first step i am asked to select the service account as follow:-

[image]

so i am not sure about these 3 points:-

1. why on the service account drop down list i got only one user, while inside my farm administration group i have three users, as follow:-

[image]

i thought i will get these 3 accounts inside the Service Account drop down list to select from inside the Configuration Wizards.

2. now as mentioned on the message under the Service Account, that i should use a service account that is different from the farm admin account. so i am not sure what does farm admin account mean ? and how i can define it ?, so i can make sure that the service account i will be using inside the Configuration Wizards is different from my Farm admin account ?
3. third question. now at this stage i check the content databases, and seems currently i do not have any content database. so will the content database be created automatically when i run the Configuration Wizards ?

Can anyone advice on the above 3 questions please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add any account into the sharepoint farm other than the one you use during the psconfig wizard when you created config db? Also advise split this question into 2 otherwise may be marked as too broad

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i manually added the "SPS FARM" to the farm administration group ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the drop down you will see only those accounts which are registered in the managed accounts. By default after fresh installation only farm admin( account you use during psconfig wizard to create config db) will be there as it is regulated in managed account.

Now if you want different service account then the farm admin account then select the create new option and enter the service account name and password then select the services you want to configure.

It is recommend don't provision the regular service application I.e search upa etc as wizard will create the database with guid in it. Only provision the state service from then rest via powershell or use central admin option

Comment: thanks for your reply. so now since the dropdown list showed only the SPadmin user, so this mean that this user was used during the psconfig wizard. is this correct? Second question, so in my case i need to use the "SPS Farm" (after defining it inside the managed accounts) as the Service account since it is not the user which is used during the psconfig wizard , is this correct? third question you did not answer my above third question, is it ok that till now i do not have any content database/s? and will the content database got created automatically during the Configuration Wizards?

Comment: 1st correct...2nd yes, because you added that in the farm admin group, not added in the managed account. For 3rd during this wizard you will see the services db being created( only for the service which you provisioned), for content database 1st you have to create a web application...during the creation you will get one content db...as I said above divide question into two because 2 question on same topic while 3rd totally different so it's hard to answer all

Comment: Yes if you want to use spafarm select it.

Comment: So now I can login with the "sps farm" to the central administration , then I can register the "sps farm" account as a managed account. Then inside the configuration wizard I can select the " sps farm " account as the service account and start the configuration wizard .. then after completing the wizards I can create a new web application and the content database will be created .. is This correct ??

Comment: No, you login with spadmin account,enter the sps farm account into managed account, then select that account while u run config wizard...again you have to login with sp admin account